# Using a Matplotlib Slider to change a surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I've created a temperature map based on several arrays (x, y, & a, where x& y are coordinates and a is the temperature). I'm trying to add a slider bar to it and keep getting

```
 TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.
```

when I try and use the slider. The initial graph is correct. As far as I can tell my inputs to the original and update are identical except for one variable (the line of the array).

```
a=np.array(Matrix)    #contains all temperatures, approx. 2000 points*4 sensors
a0=a[0]               #first set of temperatures
x=np.array([0,0,2,2])
y=np.array([0,2,0,2])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

xi, yi = np.mgrid[x.min():x.max():500j, y.min():y.max():500j]
zi = griddata(x,y,a0,xi,yi, interp='linear')

CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,50,cmap='hsv_r', vmax=M, vmin=m)
plt.colorbar(CS)
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='none',s=128, lw=1,zorder=10)

ax.scatter(x, y, c='none', s=64, lw=0)
ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', title='Title')

axsigma  = p.axes([0.25, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg='#A5D3FF') 
slider1 = Slider (axsigma, 'Datapoint',0, datapoints-2,  valinit=0,  valfmt='%0.f', dragging=True,  fc='#1E90FF')

canvas1=axsigma.figure.canvas

def update (val):
    val=int(val)
    new=a[val]
    canvas1.blit(axsigma.bbox)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c='none', s=128, lw=.1)
    zi = griddata(x,y,new,xi,yi, interp='linear')
    CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,50,cmap='hsv', vmax=M, vmin=m)    

slider1.on_changed(update)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Adding

```
a=np.array([[6.7, 6.5, 5.9, 6.0], [4.7, 4.7, 4.2, 4.2], [5.1, 5.2, 5.5, 4.9]])
M=a.max()
m=a.min()
datapoints=len(a)
```

should give enough information to run. 
By changing `new` to `zi` in `CS` within `def update`, it gets rid of the error but the slider still doesn't adjust the graph

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide a runnable example, I can only guess. One problem in what you've posted is that in the `update` function you want to actually update the artist you've plotted, not drawing an extra one. Something along the lines of

```
...
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, c='none', s=64, lw=0)
...
```

and then

```
def update(val):
   ...
   scat.set_paths(...)  # update the artist
   ...
   ax.draw()   # redraw the axes
```

Comment: Like I was saying, you should be actually updating the artist (a path collection, in case of the `scatter`). Which is not what your code is doing: you are trying to plot a new thing on top of the old plot.